# How to set the root window size to half of the screen width and height Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I am trying to get the width and height of the users monitor size. Which I can get that but now my main problem is how to set the root window to half the width ad height but I have run into a wall and I can
not find anything online that can help em what am I doing wrong here?

Here is the code:

```
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("widthxheight")
```

I am aware that it is set to go to the full screen size. Which is what I want to do first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To make the window full screen size, use this:

```
width  = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry(f'{width}x{height}')
```

To make it half the screen size, just put `/2` after `width` and `height`, like this:

```
root.geometry(f'{width/2}x{height/2}')
```

For python 3.5 and lower, use one of the following [string formatting syntaxes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
root.geometry('%sx%s' % (width/2, height/2))
# OR
root.geometry("{}x{}".format(width, height))
```

Comment: On Python 3 I was getting errors, probably due to type casting, so this works for me: ```root.geometry('%sx%s' % (int(width/1.2), int(height/1.2)))
```